# Find an approximate value of the sine of 61 degrees

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, approximation

> Use the fact that $\sin 61° = \sin (60°+1°)$ to give an approximate value of $\sin 61°$ in terms of $\pi$.

My textbook says that the answer is $(180\sqrt(3)+\pi)/360$, but I don't understand how it got there. I can expand the identity of $\sin (60°+1°)$ but I don't know where to go after that.

Comment: Do you mean 61 or 61 degree

Comment: At what level is your current knowledge?

Comment: High school mathematics, pre-calculus.

Comment: Firstly, always tag with whom you are conversing. Like this @AdityaAgarwal. Secondly, I cannot see any way of finding the answer. I think it misses some context.

Comment: One interesting thing to note is that answer is $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}+\frac{\pi}{360}=\sin60^{\circ}\cos0^{\circ}+\frac12\frac{\pi}{180}$. But what we want to calcluate is $\sin60^{\circ}\cos1^{\circ}+\frac12\sin(\frac{\pi}{180})$. But Wolfram confirms that your textbook's answer is a good approximation of $\sin61^{\circ}$, so it means that it is a very big coincidence, or we are missing something.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin61^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cos1^{\circ}+\frac12\sin1^{\circ}$$
But you are asking for it in terms of $\pi$. 
One can also use series expansion for calculating $\sin(\frac\pi3+\frac\pi{180})$.

We use the $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A$ formula and then use:
$$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-...$$
to get an approximate form. (Substitute $\frac\pi{180}$ for $x$).

---

**Addition**: Lets try something. Lets try to solve $\sin\theta=\theta$.

 We observe that $0$ is a solution, but if we put $\theta=\frac\pi{180}\approx0.0174$,we get $\sin\theta\approx0.0174$. And since you want an approximation only, I think that solves the confusion. We are asked to evaluate $$\sin61^{\circ}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cos1^{\circ}+\frac12\sin1^{\circ}\approx\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cos0+\frac12\frac{\pi}{180}$$ ($\cos1^{\circ}$ is very close to $1$). So that gives us: $$\boxed{\frac{180\sqrt3+\pi}{360}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since you want an approximate value, you can use Taylor expansion $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{3}+x\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}
   x^2}{4}-\frac{x^3}{12}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ and make $x=\frac{\pi }{180}$. Depending on the number of terms you retain, you xill get more and more accurate results.

Using the above, you will get a value $0.8746197038$ to be compared to the exact value $0.8746197072$.